# Unable to make my app show with lightsail virtual server

Tags: javascript, instance

I am trying to upload my site. it's a **node.js repo on a linux instance on amazon light sail services**.

I uploaded my source code repository to my Virtual Server Instance with static IP using `FileZilla` through a `SSh pem key`(all fine i guess..), also  I modified the file for the `apache server` as mentioned in the walk-though tutorial but, I am not able to make it show when I write `http://54.87.121.120/spanishwithalex/server/`

Before I upload my repo I tried with a simple app that worked perfectly,but now i don't know why it doesn't work. I tried various ports, different locations and various forms but I think I am walking in circles.

I attached some pictures to show where I located my files and the error messages.

I hope it's some how clear.

Thanks

[location in my instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08enM.png)

[structure repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffa9y.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnX8T.png)

[apache conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1GSh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not great on apache config, but I walked through this enough to get you going:

1. SFTP or SCP your code to a new folder called /opt/bitnami/apache2/spanishwithalex
2. Edit **/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf** using VIM or whatever and replace every line that has this **/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs**
   with this: **/opt/bitnami/apache2/spanishwithalex**

   3. Restart Apache:
      **sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache**

Let me know if that gets it working for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. ✨